# How to change font color or size of Listview item

Tags: java, android, listview

I'm looking for solution to my Listview where I would like to change the font color to red and size to any desired size of listview items.
 I've tried using adaper but I'm countering multiple error.

Here is the xml file

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:title="Space Time Alarm"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:background="#30e410"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView_Alarms"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

  


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

and Mainactivity file  is

```html
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static boolean havePermission;

    private ListView listView_Alarms;
    private FloatingActionButton button_NewAlarm;
    private Toolbar toolbar;

    private DatabaseManager databaseManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d("SPACESTOREALARM", "CREATING");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //setting up the toolbar and support
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        listView_Alarms = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView_Alarms);
        SpaceTimeAlarmManager.getInstance().initializeSpaceTimeAlarmManager(this);
        databaseManager = DatabaseManager.getInstance(this);
        databaseManager.initialize(this, listView_Alarms);
        listView_Alarms.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
                SpaceTimeAlarm alarm = (SpaceTimeAlarm) listView_Alarms.getItemAtPosition(position);
                createOrEditAlarm(alarm);
            }
        });
   
    }

   
}
```

Here list view contains list of alarms but due to same color both of font and background..the list cannot be seen. So I need help to change font color and size of listview items of above.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set an adapter and change the background color and item size like below:

```
lv = findViewById(R.id.listView);
lv.setAdaptater(adapter);
final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list) {
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // Get the current item from ListView
            View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

            // Set the text color of TextView (ListView Item)
            TextView tv = view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
            // Generate ListView Item using TextView
            tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#efefef"));
            tv.setTextSize(20);
            tv.setAllCaps(true);

                // Set a background color for ListView
                view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00afd8"));

            return view;
        }
    };
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

You can even alternate background colors.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to create a custom `ListView`.

> Check [this](https://www.journaldev.com/10416/android-listview-with-custom-adapter-example-tutorial) for creating a custom  `ListView`

With a custom `ListView` you have got a lot of more options to customize it.